# convolution layer as an output layer for classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

i am trying to build a deep learning model for classifying cifar10 dataset of 10 classes. now, i want a convolution layer as my output layer and this layer(filters=10) should take input from the flatten and predict my class.

my model code

```
num_class = 10

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Conv2D(10, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

but it is giving me error

```
Input 0 of layer conv2d_34 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 6272]
```

how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Flatten` layer before a convolutional layer. `Flatten` makes the tensor output 2-d, but `Conv2D` needs 4-d data. Just comment the `Flatten` layer line and everything will work fine.

You have no classification module in your model, you need to have a `Dense` layer with number of classes in the last layer.

```
#model.add(Flatten()) # comment this line
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(10,(3,3)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(num_class)) # num_class is how many classes do you have in your dataset
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

You can use convolution layer as final output with some kind of global pooling. For example, the following model uses GlobalAveragePooling.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))


model.add(Conv2D(10, (3,3)))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.summary()
```